# WATCH OS: How to seek WKInterfaceInlineMovie

Tags: swift, video, operating-system, watch, wkinterfacecontroller

Successfully played a video using 'WKInterfaceInlineMovie'. However, I need an option to start the video from the middle. Is this possible? Also, there is no delegate method to know when the video ends.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is currently not possible. According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfaceinlinemovie), the playback can only be controlled using

- pause()
- play()
- playFromBeginning()

Comment: Is seeking possible in any other way, if i don't use WKInterfaceInlineMovie?

Comment: I am sorry, I don‘t know any other way to achieve what you want.